# com.google.android.gcm.server.InvalidRequestException: sending FCM message

Tags: java, firebase, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

Hi I am getting this as response while sending the FCM message

**Error posting messages**com.google.android.gcm.server.InvalidRequestException: HTTP Status Code: 400(Error=DeprecatedEndpoint) in code i am using **gcm-server.jar**  in my **play 2.1.2** project

i have send message using https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send there i am getting success response with the same data but if i try via code it throws an error

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                MulticastResult multicastResult;
                try {

                    Sender sender = new Sender(Constants.ANDORIED_APP_ID_FCM);
                    multicastResult = sender.send(message1, devices, Constants.ANDROID_GCM_RETRY_COUNT);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    CabhoundLogger.error("Error posting messages" + e, className);
                    errorCount++;

                    return;
                }
```

Comment: Read the error message. It's very descriptive. GCM was deprecated (in May of 2018 to be precise). https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/faq. Switch to FireBase Cloud Messaging.

Comment: but i am sending messages by using FCM only. In server side my project code contains gcm-server.jar. I hope that is not deprecated yet. but i am getting the failure message while sending message

Comment: `gcm-server` is deprecated, as both the exception and the docs I linked tell you.

Comment: okay then what is the alternative for the gcm-server.jar can you suggest something? (also i am facing this problem only  from few days(around 7 days ) but i know GCM is deprecated long back).

Comment: @ Jenifer : Did you get any Solution ?

Comment: Nop @DhavalPatel but i have replaced my code with FCM server jar